# Метасократ без шляпы

Tags: поддержка, знаки, новогодние-шляпы

Получил [второго сократа на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic?userid=178988), а шляпу за золотой знак что-то не выдают :(

[image: знак]

[image: шляпы]

[image: ещё шляпы]

Comment: У меня тоже за золото Foot of the Rainbow с большой задержкой выдали, много больше чем типовые 15 минут. Возможно, на них стоит реже проверка? Или всё ещё проще: знак нужно заработать на основном сайте, а не на его мете?

Comment: Так на мете не дают шляпы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шляпы даются только на главных сайтах, мета сайты к ним не относятся. Исключение — главный Meta Stack Exchange. При этом некоторые шляпы могут даваться за действия на Мете, но появятся они всё равно в профиле главного сайта.

Можно еще заметить, что если в мета-профиле нажать на снежинку, произойдёт редирект на профиль основного сайта и после этого уже откроется список полученных шляп.

Comment: Ну вот :( Эх...

Comment: @Qwertiy не стоит расчитывать, что шляпы не будут вести себя шляпно.